# Parsing links with JTidy

Tags: java, html-parsing, jtidy

I am currently using JTidy to parse an HTML document and fetch a collection of all anchor tags in the given HTML document.  I then extract the value of each tag's href attribute to come up with a collection of links on the page.

Unfortunately, these links can be expressed in a few different ways: some absolute (`http://www.example.com/page.html`), some relative (`/page.html`, `page.html`, or `../page.html`). Even more, some can just be anchors (`#paragraphA`).  When I visit my page in a browser, it knows automatically how to handle these different href values if I were to click the link, however if I were to follow one of these links retrieved from JTidy using an HTTPClient programatically, I first need to provide a valid URL (so e.g. I would first need to transform /page.html, page.html, and http://www.example.com/page.html to http://www.example.com/page.html).

Is there some built-in functionality, whether in JTidy or elsewhere, that can achieve this for me?  Or will I need to create my own rules to transform these different URLs into an absolute URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vanilla URL class might get you most of the way there, assuming you can work out which context to use. Here are some examples:

```
package grimbo.url;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class TestURL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // context1
        URL c1 = u(null, "http://www.example.com/page.html");
        u(c1, "http://www.example.com/page.html");
        u(c1, "/page.html");
        u(c1, "page.html");
        u(c1, "../page.html");
        u(c1, "#paragraphA");

        System.out.println();

        // context2
        URL c2 = u(null, "http://www.example.com/path/to/page.html");
        u(c2, "http://www.example.com/page.html");
        u(c2, "/page.html");
        u(c2, "page.html");
        u(c2, "../page.html");
        u(c2, "#paragraphA");
    }

    public static URL u(URL context, String url) {
        try {
            URL u = null != context ? new URL(context, url) : new URL(url);
            System.out.println(u);
            return u;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
http://www.example.com/page.html
http://www.example.com/page.html
http://www.example.com/page.html
http://www.example.com/page.html
http://www.example.com/../page.html
http://www.example.com/page.html#paragraphA

http://www.example.com/path/to/page.html
http://www.example.com/page.html
http://www.example.com/page.html
http://www.example.com/path/to/page.html
http://www.example.com/path/page.html
http://www.example.com/path/to/page.html#paragraphA
```

As you can see, there are some results that aren't what you want. So maybe you try and parse the URL using `new URL(value)` first, and if that results in a `MalformedURLException` you could try relative to a context URL.

Answer (score 1):

Your best best is most likely to follow the same resolution process that browsers do, as [outlined in the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#resolving-relative-uris):

> User agents must calculate the base URI according to the following
>   precedences (highest priority to lowest):
>
> 1. The base URI is set by the BASE element.
> 2. The base URI is given by meta data discovered during a protocol interaction, such as an HTTP header (see [RFC2616]).
> 3. By default, the base URI is that of the current document. Not all HTML documents have a base URI (e.g., a valid HTML document may appear
>      in an email and may not be designated by a URI). Such HTML documents
>      are considered erroneous if they contain relative URIs and rely on a
>      default base URI.

In practice, you're probably most concerned with numbers 1 and 2 (i.e. check for a `<base href="..."` and use either that (if it exists) or the URI of the current document).